# Client/server sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, echo

I am currently trying to understand how to use sockets to make a client/server program in C. I have been reading various tutorials around the Internet in hopes to try and make a small echo server that can deal with multiple clients at the same time. Whenever the client sends the server a message, the server is supposed to echo is back to the client. The code that I created is a combination of both a tutorial from a lecture at school (which explained how to create the client and server) as well as an example I found on here on stackoverflow (which showed how to make the functions to actually echo the messages). I am hoping that someone can explain to me what I am missing to make this program work correctly. Here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

char buf[80];
struct sockaddr myname;

void replyBack(FILE *fp, int sockfd) {
char sendline[1000], recvline[1000];
printf("Enter your echo: \n");
while(fgets(sendline,1000,stdin) != NULL) {
    write(sockfd,sendline,sizeof(sendline));
    if(read(sockfd,recvline,1000) == 0) {
        printf("str_cli: server terminated prematurely");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fputs(recvline, stdout);
}
}

main() {
int sock, adrlen, cnt;

sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock < 0) {
    printf("client socket failure%d\n", errno);
    printf("client: ");
    exit(1);
}

myname.sa_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(myname.sa_data, "/tmp/billb");
adrlen = strlen(myname.sa_data) + sizeof(myname.sa_family);

if(connect(sock, &myname, adrlen) < 0) {
    printf("client connect failure %d\n", errno);
    perror("client: ");
    exit(1);
}

replyBack(stdin,sock);
exit(0);
}
```

And here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

struct sockaddr myname;
char buf[80];

void echo(int sockfd) {
ssize_t n;
int write_err;
char buf[1000];
char * send_start_pos;
while(1) {
    bytes_in = read(sockfd, buf, 1000);
    if(bytes_in < 1) {
        if(errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        break;
    }
    bytes_remaining = bytes_in;
    send_start_pos = buf;
    write_err = 0;

    while((bytes_remaining > 0) && !(write_err)) {
        bytes_out = write(sockfd, send_start_pos,           
                bytes_remaining);
        if(bytes_out < 0) {
            if(errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            write_err = 1;
            break;
        }
    bytes_remaining -= bytes_out;
    send_start_pos += bytes_out;
    }
    if(write_err)
        break;
}
}

main() {
int sock, new_sd, adrlen, cnt;

sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock < 0) {
    printf("server socket failure %d\n", errno);
    perror("server: ");
    exit(1);
}

myname.sa_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(myname.sa_data, "/tmp/billb");
adrlen = strlen(myname.sa_data) + sizeof(myname.sa_family);

unlink("/tmp/billb"); /*defensive programming */
if(bind(sock, &myname, adrlen) < 0) {
    printf("server bind failure%d\n", errno);
    perror("server: ");
    exit(1);
}

if(listen(sock, 5) < 0) {
    printf("server listen failure %d\n", errno);
    perror("server: ");
    exit(1);
}

while(1) {
    if(new_sd = accept(sock, &myname, &adrlen) < 0) {
        printf("server accept failure %d\n", errno);
        perror("server: ");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Socket address in server %d is %s, %s\n", 
        getpid(), myname.sa_data, myname.sa_data);

    if(fork() == 0) {
        close(sock);
        echo(new_sd);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(new_sd);
}
}
```

The problem when I run the program is that the client is accepting the message but then does not actually send it to the server, so the server can never echo it back.

I know this is probably basic stuff so I appreciate your patience and time!

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: edited it at the bottom to hopefully make it clearer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> adrlen = strlen(myname.sa_data) + sizeof(myname.sa_family);
> ```

This should be `sizeof myname`. The `unix(7)` sockets are actually defined to have a `sockaddr_un` like this:

```
       #define UNIX_PATH_MAX    108

       struct sockaddr_un {
           sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
           char        sun_path[UNIX_PATH_MAX];  /* pathname */
       };
```

You've given it `10+4` as the size. Which should almost work -- it doesn't count the terminating `NUL` byte at the end of the filename -- but even with the `+ 1` added, I'd feel better if you're passing in exactly the size of object you have. (Be careful of `strlen(3)` on strings. Almost always you need a `+ 1` in any expression that involves `strlen(3)`. Funny.)

> ```
> while(fgets(sendline,1000,stdin) != NULL) {
>     write(sockfd,sendline,sizeof(sendline));
> ```

And here you're sending all 1000 bytes of your buffer, regardless of contents. The user might have entered one character, or one hundred, and you're sending all 1000 bytes of whatever is at that address.

Your `echo` method is a bit much; I'd recommend splitting the writing off into its own routine; [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079) (a *superb* book, well worth finding a copy if you expect to program Unix or Unix-like systems) has a small sweet routine I really enjoy:

> ```
> ssize_t             /* Write "n" bytes to a descriptor  */
> writen(int fd, const void *ptr, size_t n)
> {
>     size_t      nleft;
>     ssize_t     nwritten;
>
>     nleft = n;
>     while (nleft > 0) {
>         if ((nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
>             if (nleft == n)
>                 return(-1); /* error, return -1 */
>             else
>                 break;      /* error, return amount written so far */
>         } else if (nwritten == 0) {
>             break;
>         }
>         nleft -= nwritten;
>         ptr   += nwritten;
>     }
>     return(n - nleft);      /* return >= 0 */
> }
> ```

(See `lib/writen.c` in the [source from the book's website](http://www.apuebook.com/).)

I haven't actually *tried* your code, so it's very possible none of these are the problem actually preventing your software from working :) if that's the case, leave a comment, and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: so instead of sending the entire buffer, would I use something like strlen(sendline)? that makes sense :)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that thanks to your detailed answer I was able to get my program working and so I feel like I understand sockets well enough now to try writing my own client/server from scratch. We'll see how that goes!

Comment: @A D, excellent, glad to hear it :) but don't overlook @cnicutar, he spotted the bug that'd keep it from working. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a truckload of includes. I took the time to compile your programs and this gem stood out of the crowd of warnings

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

At this line

```
if(new_sd = accept(sock, &myname, &adrlen) < 0) {
```

So basically you're checking if accept returns something lower than 0 and assigning that to new_sd. Change that line to

```
if((new_sd = accept(sock, &myname, &adrlen)) < 0) {
```

**Bonus**:
Most of what @sarnold said in his answer is correct and in the long run will do you better than my answer.

Comment: Hah! I can't tell you how many times I've made that typo myself. Good catch! :)