# multithreading concept in client server program

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, server, client

my program only works as read operation for server and write operation for client side.How can I do read and write operations for both client and server using multithreading concept.

I'm able to write message on client side but not able to write on server side. please help me to solve this problem.

```
/*server function*/
int server(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        int sock_fd,socknew_fd,portNo,cliLen;//socket file descriptor-sock_fd
        char buff[256];
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
        int n;

       /*first call to socket function*/
        sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); /*socket created of family type IP v4 ,socket type TCP and 0 indicates default protocol to be selected*/

        if(sock_fd<0)  //if -1(sock_fd) returned by socket() it shows socket cant be created
        {
                perror("error opening socket");
                exit(0);
        }

        /*initialize socket structure*/
        bzero((char *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));//setting all default structure socket values to 0

                portNo=atoi(argv[1]);
                serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
                serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
                serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portNo);
        //initialize family,server address,portno which should be of network order

        /*now bind the host address using bind() call*/
        if(bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
        {perror("error in binding");
        exit(1);
        }
        /*start listening for client and be in sleep mode till any request arises from client*/
        while(1)
         {
                 listen(sock_fd,5);
                cliLen=sizeof(cli_addr);


                /*accept actual connection from client*/
                socknew_fd=accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&cliLen);
                if(socknew_fd<0)
                {
                        perror("error in accept");
                        exit(1);
                }

                 /*if connection is established start communicating*/
                 bzero(buff,256);
                 n=read(socknew_fd,buff,255);
                 if(buff[0]==32)
                        break;
                if(n<0)
                {perror("error in reading from socket");
                exit(1);
                }

                 printf("here is message:%s\n",buff);

                 /*write a response to client*/
                 n=write(socknew_fd,"I got your message",18);
                 if(n<0)
                 {perror("error writing in socket");
                 exit(1);
                 }


         }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, `while(1)  { listen(sock_fd,5); ....` - that is assuredly an error. That `listen` belongs *outside* the loop (after the bind, before the loop starts). The listen queue on a server socket need only be established *once*. The loop takes over per-client duties (usually routing `accept`-ed connections into a different thread or work queue managing threads, or a `select` polling loop, all of which are ripe for research).

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: ``if(bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
        {perror("error in binding");
        exit(1);
        }`  for ease of readability and understanding, please consistently indent the code.  Strongly suggest each indent level be 4 spaces, not a tab

Comment: regarding: `int n;` and `n=read(socknew_fd,buff,255);` and `n=write(socknew_fd,"I got your message",18);`  The returned type from `read()` and from `write()` is `ssize_t`   NOT `int`

Comment: Please post the code for the 'client'

Comment: `void bzero(void *s, size_t n);`   This is the syntax for function: `bzero()`  Note that the parameter types in the syntax do not match this statement in the code: `bzero((char *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));`  Strongly suggest reading/understanding the MAN page for each C library function used

Comment: regarding: `int sock_fd,socknew_fd,portNo,cliLen;` and `socknew_fd=accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&cliLen);`  The syntax for `accept()` is `int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`  So the declaration of `cliLen` should be: `socklen_t cliLen;`

Comment: Note: there are many many examples of how to code a client<>server connection and communication on stackoverflow.com  A search criteria similar to: `stackoverflow: client server in c`  will find: [client-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945895/client-server-sockets-in-c)

Comment: the `read()` function does not automatically NUL terminate the read message, so `printf("here is message:%s\n",buff)` will result in undefined behavior.  Suggest (after a successful read)  `buff[n] = '\0';`